# How do I defeat Sproink?

Tags: yo-kai-watch

Sproink has the lucky underwear I need to give to the man who can upgrade my watch.  Problem is, I can't defeat him. I have tried three times now and died every time. I know I do more damage when I hit Sproink in the bellybutton with my attacks, but he keeps covering it up so I can't hit it.

What's the best way to defeat him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Sproink protects his weak spot (belly button) he then leaves his head exposed. While not a weak point, if you attack it, it will annoy him enough to cover his head, uncovering his weak spot.

Keep alternating between head and belly button and you should have no problem keeping the damage up.